# How can I disable a bathroom ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, television

I need to be able to disable an electrical wire, what is the safest way to do it? I cannot just leave it unplugged and I cannot cut it. I'm able to shut off the main electricity from the house to do it safely. Don't ask why, I just need to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For most devices, turn off power, disconnect wires from device and cap each wire with a wire nut.  Can be done at device or switch.

Comment: Just to add, the capped wire should be inside a listed junction box with an appropriate cover.

Comment: Where does this fan plug in & why can't you just leave it unplugged? Maybe [edit] your post to include a picture of the bathroom with the fan, then a close up of the fan plug in.

Comment: Is this in any way related to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/237772/34147) that was asked about a week ago? If so, you're going to get the same lack of response because you've provided the same lack of information. If not, learn from that question and provide some details so we can actually help you. Otherwise, we're just guessing blind - none of us can see your situation through our monitors.

Comment: @asdf If you want to remove the message, don't change it to gibberish, delete it.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, the same person who posted the question I linked to. We got the exact same response of vandalizing the post when the other one was closed due to lack of information.

Answer (score 2):

Most bathroom fans have the rough in housing hardwired, but the fan in many cases is simply plugged into the rough in housing. If you want to disable the fan, remove the grill and unplug it and reset the grill.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fan is controlled by some sort of switch - whether a simple manual switch, humidity activated, mechanical timer, etc. - I would open the switch and disconnect either the hot wire or the switched hot wire. One of the pros may speak up with a preference, but my gut feeling is that if the switch has permanently attached wires then disconnect the hot wire (i.e., remove it from the wire nut connecting it to the incoming hot) and if the switch has screws then disconnect the switched hot wire. In either case, cap the disconnected wire with a wire nut.

The problem with disconnecting at the fan is that some fans have plug-in connections but some have wires with wire nuts connecting to the incoming wires crammed inside an attached junction box and *you are working on this on a ladder at the ceiling* instead of much more easily at the wall switch.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire fan assembly from the housing. It's as simple a unplugging. Probably won't even need a tool. I'd ask why, but you said not to.